# Referencing a form fails without error message

Tags: vba, ms-access

The following vba code in ms access 2016 (32bit)
Fails without providing a message only a beep is heard.

```
If IsFormLoaded("frmSearch") = true then
 DoCmd.close acform, "frmSearch"
end if
```

The form is a pop-up one and  it and it's controls are all unbound
This has always worked in the past
Machine is intel based running linux mint with windows 10 running in virtual box

Some other functionality seems to be missing in vba with regard
to referencing forms in general.

Everything else seems to be working fine. I am trying to run the code from a button event on frmClients. Any help given would be highly appreciated. This was me trying to find what the problem was with regards to referencing forms.

Comment: IsFormLoaded is not an intrinsic function - must be a custom function. So failure must be within that function code.

Comment: Have you tested If (CurrentProject.AllForms("frmSearch").IsLoaded) Then ... ?